# Period of a discrete sine function?

Tags: trigonometry, signal-processing, periodic-functions

My teacher assigned me a problem involving a discrete periodic function and I'm a little confused on how to solve.

Here is what was assigned (I paraphrased/summarized a bit):

*For the given function sin((2f/fs)∙n∙T) find the integer value of T>1 such that the function is a periodic discrete signal. (multiple possible answers)*

*Variables given: f = 32 Hz, fs = 200*

Part of the assignment involved using MATLAB to plot the function, which I think I managed to figure out. I ended up finding that a value of T=13 was a possible integer value which made the function a periodic discrete signal

The problem I have is I don't know how to mathematically explain why a value of T=13 works.

I tried to find a formula but I'm not sure how to apply it for my case, nor am I able to figure out any other values of T.

**Does anyone know how I can either explain why T=13 works, or provide me a formula to find a more correct answer?**

Note: I am really unfamiliar with signal stuff at all this was an assignment given in a class called "advanced engineering mathematics" which usually covers more differential equation stuff so if there are different tags or a different forum I should use pls let me know lol

Comment: I'm not familiar with discrete periodic functions, but in this case notice that the period is $P=4T/25$ so perhaps you should look at values of $T$ which are multiples of $25/4$, such as $T=6.25, 12.5, 18.75,\cdots$. Could it be that 12.5 is a better fit than 13?

Comment: That's what I was thinking too. The reason I rounded up to 13 was because my teacher said the number had to be an integer. Thanks for your help I really appreciate it!

Comment: Well, then I suppose $T=25$ would be a candidate.

Comment: I meant to say $P=\dfrac{25}{4T}$.